# Conditional types ReturnType function signature overload resolution

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, typescript2.8

I'm trying to use typescript 2.8's new [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316), (not yet released version 2.8.0-dev.20180307) and I don't know if this is a bug or just a misuse.  My focus is on my declaration of `MockedImplementation<F>` which can be a full function matching `F`, the return type of `F`, and if the return type of `F` is a `Promise`, then it could also be what the promise resolves to - all to be wrapped accordingly by `mockIt()`.

```
type MockedImplementation<F> = 
    F | // The function signature
    ((ReturnType<F extends (...args: any[]) => any ? F : any>) extends infer T 
        ? T extends Promise<infer R> 
            ? (T | R) // Or the promise or just the type that the promise resolves to
            : T // or whatever type this is
        : never);

interface Wrapped<T> {
    result: T
}

function mockIt<F>(pretend : MockedImplementation<F>) : F {
    throw new Error('Not Implemented'); // doesn't matter
}

interface SomeOperationA {
    (parameters : { 'a': number[], 'b'?: string }) : Promise<string>;
}

mockIt<SomeOperationA>(() => Promise.resolve('hello')); //  OK
mockIt<SomeOperationA>(Promise.resolve('hello')); //  OK
mockIt<SomeOperationA>('hello'); //  OK
mockIt<SomeOperationA>(42); //  Type error.
```

`mockIt` of `SomeOperationA` works, perhaps directly because there are no function signature overrides.  But `mockIt` of `SomeOperationB` fails:

```
interface SomeOperationB {
    (parameters : { 'a': number[], 'b'?: string }) : Promise<string>;
    (parameters : { 'a': number[], 'b'?: string }, rawResponse : true) : Promise<Wrapped<string>>;
    (parameters : { 'a': number[], 'b'?: string }, rawResponse : false) : Promise<string>;
}

mockIt<SomeOperationB>(() => Promise.resolve('hello')); // ❌ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Wrapped<string>'.
mockIt<SomeOperationB>(Promise.resolve('hello')); //  OK
mockIt<SomeOperationB>('hello'); //  OK
mockIt<SomeOperationB>(42); //  Type error.
```

It seems to be intersecting types instead of unioning them?  But I'm sure it is more nuanced than that.

I saw a note somewhere about "considers the last overload because presumably it is the most generalized", but I don't think it is relevant here because it doesn't seem to behave as though it matters.

#### Edit

@jcalz is right, makes sense:

```
interface SomeOperationB {
    (wrapped : true) : Promise<Wrapped<string>>;
    (wrapped : false) : Promise<string>;
}

interface Wrapped<T> { result: T }

declare function acceptSomeOperationB(x: SomeOperationB): void;

acceptSomeOperationB(() => Promise.resolve('hello')); // ❌ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Wrapped<string>'.
acceptSomeOperationB(() => Promise.resolve({ result: 'hello' })); // ❌ Type '{ result: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A smaller reproduction of your problem with no conditional types:

```
declare function acceptSomeOperationB(x: SomeOperationB): void;
acceptSomeOperationB(() => Promise.resolve('hello')); // ❌ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Wrapped<string>'.
```

It is clear that TypeScript does not consider the arrow function to be compatible with `SomeOperationB` because it fails to meet one of the overloaded signatures.  Indeed, if you pass `true` as the second parameter to that function, it will *not* return a `Promise<Wrapped<string>>`, as required by the second signature for `SomeOperationB`.

Once you decide how to resolve that, it should start working (or you can at least move on to issues with conditional types.)

Good luck.